# Can I get a 1 day extension from the FRRO in India on a 1 year Indian business visa for a 1-day overstay due to flight time change

Tags: visas, india, overstaying

I have a 1 year Indian business visa which expires 3rd December. My international departing flight was at 2am on the 4, but has now been changed by 4 hours to 6am on the 4th meaning I will not be able to check into the flight and pass through immigration early enough to make it before midnight on the 3rd. I would now leave through immigration one day late. 
Can I apply for a 1-day extension to allow for this situation without any repercussions for future business visa applications.

PS I am trying to cancel the flight through the airline, but in the meantime want to know my options.

Comment: Can you just pass through immigration 4 hours earlier and thus are not in the US?

Comment: I won't be able to check in that early. It is India, not the US and check in will commence 4 hours before, ie 2am

Comment: As a general guide an Indian visa will only be extended on reasonable grounds eg medical reasons; if you overstay you will need an exit visa and you could be fined. https://boi.gov.in/content/requirments-extension-visa

Comment: If your flight has been rescheduled, you should have grounds to go back to the airline and request an earlier flight (or a refund, though check the terms and conditions) without paying a change fee.

Comment: @Traveller thanks. I will literally be 2 hours overstay, so want to find out if they'll find the flight reschedule reasonable grounds to extend by 24 hours.

Comment: @Zach Lipton thanks. I am asking the airline for a full refund, but just researching all my options.

Comment: The airline may be more willing to reschedule you on a flight a day or two earlier than to issue a full refund.